# Expect: Getting string at run time

Tags: tcl, expect

Is there any way to get strings at run time?
(say like scanf function in "C" we can enter string at run time)

Answer (score -1):

If you are speaking of C#

The **Console.ReadLine** should do the work for you !

You can get more details here - http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.console.readline.aspx

Comment: ex: set name "Tamin"; Instead of assigning the string :Tamin" to "name", i want to assign the string to "name" at run time

Comment: -1 He's talking about expect, which isn't a C# library (and even a minimal search would show that).

Comment: @Donal - I had mentioned clearly if it is C# ! His question was not so clear..From his question I thought he is expecting an API ..lol ... I did not deserve a downvote for this :(

Comment: @GuruC He tagged it with [tag:expect], and that's got a tag wiki that explains exactly what it means…

Answer (score -1):

Yes, you can use **read** to accept strings, or **gets** to read a line. See here for more info: http://www.tcl.tk/man/tcl8.5/TclCmd/read.htm

Comment: Won't work with expect in the mix; it modifies the behavior of `gets` (or rather of reading from stdin).

Answer (score -1):

The equivalent of C's scanf() is this in standard Tcl:

```
scan [gets stdin] "the pattern..." var1 var2 ...
```

With expect though, you need to use `expect_user`:

```
expect_user -re "(.*)\n"
scan $expect_out(1,string) "the pattern..." var1 var2 ...
```

Comment: The documentation for `scan` is [online](http://www.tcl.tk/man/tcl8.5/TclCmd/scan.htm); it's very close to a good sscanf(), but not quite the same. (In particular, it doesn't have any of the buffer overflow issues or other memory smashing problems…)

Comment: And here's the [expect manual](http://www.tcl.tk/man/expect5.31/expect.1.html); search for `expect_user` within it.

Comment: you don't *need* to use expect_user: expect is an extension of Tcl, so you get all of Tcl's goodness at your disposal.